# Как обработать критическую ошибку при старте службы Windows?

Tags: c#, service

При старте службы windows возникает критическая ошибка требующая останова еще не стартовавшей службы. Ошибку логирую. Но что делать с ней дальше? Как сообщить windows, чтобы она не считала службу запущенной? Можно ли как то информировать пользователя о том что служба не запущена?

Спасибо.

Comment: Если служба не стартовала, то с чего вдруг винда будет считать её запущенной? А что и как пользователю сообщать — это исключительно ваше дело, стандартов нет.

Comment: @Discord Винда по моему считает запущенной службу для которой вызван метод .ServiceBase.OnStart. А вот как сообщить Service Control Manager, что служба не запущена - не знаю. По-поводу сообщить пользователю: можно ли из программы службы вывести диалоговое окно с сообщением?

Comment: По-моему, винда считает запущенной службу, процесс которой существует. Хотите сказать, оснастка Services отображает вашу службу как запущенную, когда процесс уже умер? Или проблема в том, чтобы убить процесс?

Comment: @Discord Проблема в том что я не знаю что и как делать: сообщить винде, что служба не запущена; остановить ее, прибить весь процесс целиком.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если сервис не смог корректно запуститься - то достаточно просто остановить его из кода, вызовом Stop():

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // случилась ошибка?
    this.Stop();
}
```

Он перейдет обратно в Stopped. Если при этом попытка запуска была инициирована пользователем - тому покажется стандартное сообщение вида

> The Service12 service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Comment: Спасибо. Это то что доктор прописал

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял:
У вас при инициализации службы происходит критическая ошибка. Вы с помощью try/catch её перехватываете, пишете сообщение в лог. В этот момент остановить службу вы не можете, так как она еще не запустилась. 
Возможные решения:

1. Заведите переменную типа bool, и при вызове метода OnStart проверяйте её значение. В OnStart вы можете остановить службу.
2. Я бы посоветовал вам не использовать код, который может привести к ошибке, в конструкторе. По возможности, постарайтесь перенести его в метод OnStart.

Comment: Нет ошибка возникает в OnStart. А вот дальше я не знаю что и как делать: сообщить винде, что служба не запущена; остановить ее, прибить весь процесс целиком.